# Haskell answers generator

Tags: haskell, prolog

I want to write a function that should produce multiple answers for same agruments. Something like:

```
aux [x,y]
  | x == A && y == B  = [A,B1]
  | x == A && y == B  = [A,B2]
```

As you can see both conditions are the same so I am only getting one answer `[A,B1]`, but I want `[A,B1]` and then `[A,B2]`.
So, basicly, I want haskell to work like prolog. Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you just return a list of the answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
import Control.Monad (guard)

data A = A | B | B1 | B2 deriving Eq
aux [x, y] = concat
             [ guard (x == A && y == B) >> [[A, B1]]
             , guard (x == A && y == B) >> [[A, B2]]]
```

This is just using the list monad and to build up arguments, if the condition is false we just give the empty list, and then concating the results.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to build internal list of answers and return it as a result.